# SoapClient Class not found laravel Command

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to use SoapClient class from a command in laravel 5 with no success, my SoapClient Class is already enabled in php.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that my composer installation was pointing to another php installation, so I just fix the php installation pointed by composer and it worked.